# assign output of print to a variable in python

Tags: python

i want to know how to assign the output of print to a variable.

so if

```
mystring = "a=\'12\'"
```

then

```
print mystring 
a=12
```

and i want to pass this  like  **kwargs,

```
test(mystring)
```

how can i do this?

for more of an explanation: i have a list of strings i got from a a comment line of a data file. it looks like this:

```
"a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='45um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='60um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='75um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 '']
```

i want to put the values into some structure so i can plot the various things versus any variabls so the list is a legend basically, and i want to plot functions of the traces versus variables given in teh legend.

so if for each entry i have a trace, then i may want to plot max(trace) vs offX for a series of a values.

and my first idea was to pass the strings as **kwargs to a function which would produce a matrix of corresponding data.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear what you are actually trying to do, but if it's some `eval()`-like functionality it probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way, personally. A far less hackish solution is to build a dictionary from your data first, and then pass it whole to a function as `**kwargs`. For example (this isn't the most elegant way to do it, but it is illustrative):

```
import re

remove_non_digits = re.compile(r'[^\d.]+')

inputList = ["a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='45um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='60um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='75um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'", '']

#remove empty strings
flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        inputList.remove('')
    except ValueError:
        flag=False

outputList = []

for varString in inputList:
    varStringList = varString.split()
    varDict = {}
    for aVar in varStringList:
        varList = aVar.split('=')
        varDict[varList[0]] = varList[1]
    outputList.append(varDict)

for aDict in outputList:
    for aKey in aDict:
        aDict[aKey] = float(remove_non_digits.sub('', aDict[aKey]))

print outputList
```

This prints:

```
[{'a': 0.014999999999999999, 'offY': 75.0, 'offX': 45.0, 'twistLength': 0.0, 'lPrime': 0.29199999999999998, 'sPrime': 0.39300000000000002}, {'a': 0.014999999999999999, 'offY': 75.0, 'offX': 60.0, 'twistLength': 0.0, 'lPrime': 0.29199999999999998, 'sPrime': 0.39300000000000002}, {'a': 0.014999999999999999, 'offY': 75.0, 'offX': 75.0, 'twistLength': 0.0, 'lPrime': 0.29199999999999998, 'sPrime': 0.39300000000000002}]
```

Which appears to be exactly what you want.

Comment: this is very good. a bit involved, but i think the best solution. 


this is problem arose because the plaintext file i am looking at is really a series of  traces for many design variations. i just need a way to consolidate the data and look at somthing understandable, like Max(trace) vs parameterX, and all the parameters are given in the first line as a comment, but the order of these correspond to the order of the columns given in teh data portion. 



i hope this is clear and not very rambling. 
anyway, thanks a lot. 

alex

Comment: This can almost certainly be done far more elegantly and in fewer lines of code. Also, if you think it's the best answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Redirect `stdout` and capture its output in an object?

```
import sys

# a simple class with a write method
class WritableObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    def write(self, string):
        self.content.append(string)

# example with redirection of sys.stdout
foo = WritableObject()                   # a writable object
sys.stdout = foo                         # redirection

print "one, two, three, four"            # some writing
```

And then just take the "output" from `foo.content` and do what you want with it.

Please disregard if I have misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: +1 mostly agree...eventually might want to re-access original sys.stdout to actually print something.  so do this `sys_stdout_save = sys.stdout` before re-assigning sys.stdout

Comment: @AJ: of course one would prefer to `rewire` stdout at an appropriate time. It isn't really clear what the poster wants to achieve anyways IMO.

Comment: +1 regardless of OP's actual intent, it is useful to know how to "hi-jack" sys.stdout.  And yeah, one may want to preserve it to re-instate regular output at a later time but that is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `__str__` and `__repr__` on python objects to get their string representations (there's a tiny difference between them, so consult the docs). That's actually done by `print` internally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of these two things will accomplish what you're looking for:

The Python exec statement: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec
or the Python eval function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval

Both of them let you dynamically evaluate strings as Python code.

**UPDATE:**

What about:

```
def calltest(keywordstr):
    return eval("test(" + keywordstr + ")")
```

I think that will do what you're looking for.

Comment: this is close but i cant get it to work. 
i want to evaluate a string and pass it to a function like kwargs

Comment: Could you not do something like `eval("test(" + mystring + ")")`?

Answer (score 0):

for more of an explanation:
i have a list of strings i got from a a comment line of a data file. 
   it looks like this:

```
"a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='45um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='60um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 "a='0.015in' lPrime='0.292' offX='75um' offY='75um' sPrime='0.393' twistLength='0'",
 '']
```

i want to put the values into some structure so i can plot the various things versus any variabls 
so the list is a legend basically, and i want to plot functions of the traces versus variables given in teh legend.

so if for each entry i have a trace, then i may want to plot max(trace) vs offX for a series of a values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string 'my_string' like this:

```
a=123 b=456 c='hello'
```

Then you can pass it to a function 'my_fun' like this:

```
my_fun(**eval('{' + my_string.replace(' ', ',') + '}'))
```

Depending on the precise formatting of my_string, you may have to vary this a little, but this should get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: i tried this and got a syntax error, im also not sure of the theory behind it.